# Python align text using a for loop

Tags: python

Im trying to align some next using a for loop as follows

```
def display_name(first_name,last_name,align1,length1,align2,length2):

 str = ""
 
 #first name
 #align left
 if align1 == "L":
   str = first_name
   for i in range(0, length1 - len(first_name)):
       str += " "
 print("First name")       
 print(str)
 
 #align right
 if align1 == "R":
   str = first_name
   for i in range(0, length1 - len(first_name)):
       str += " "
       str += first_name
 print("First name")       
 print(str)
 
 #align centre
 if align1 == "C":
   str = first_name
   for i in range(0, length1 - len(first_name)):
       str += " "
       str += first_name
 print("First name")       
 print(str)


 display_name("John", "Smith", "L", 12, "R", 10)
```

As you can see I have 3 main blocks of code, one for each alignment type. When I run my code the left alignment works, however, the right and the centre alignment does not as all text is aligned to the left

```
First name
John        
First name
John        
First name
John
```

any help in getting the text to align centre and right WITHOUT using format, it has to be for loops, would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see is that your right and centre aligns are putting the name in first, and then repeating it. What about trying this:

```
def display_name(first_name,last_name,align1,length1,align2,length2):
  str = ""

  # Left section leave as is

  #align right
    if align1 == "R":
      # Put the spaces in first, THEN the name.    
      for i in range(0, length1 - len(first_name)):
        str += " "
      str += first_name               
      print("First name")
      print(str)

  #align centre
    if align1 == "C":
      # Put in half the spaces first, THEN the name, THEN the rest of the spaces.
      for i in range(0, (length1 - len(first_name))//2):
        str += " "
      str += first_name 
      for i in range(0, length1 - len(str)):
        str += " "
      print("First name")
      print(str)
```

Obviously update for the last name as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use then I would suggest using the standard string functions for formatting.

- ljust : Left justify
- rjust : Right justify
- center : Center

#### Sample

```
def display_name(first_name,last_name,align1,length1,align2,length2):  
  align_map = {
      "L": str.ljust,
      "R": str.rjust,
      "C": str.center
  }
  print("First name")
  print (align_map[align1](first_name, length1))

  print("Last name")
  print (align_map[align2](last_name, length2))

  # Or just
  # print(f"First name:\n{align_map[align1](first_name, length1)}\nLast name:\n{align_map[align2](last_name, length2)}")

display_name("John", "Smith", "L", 12, "R", 10)
```

Output:

```
First name
John        
Last name
     Smith
```